# Can I sort a pandas DataFrame by a function [of each row]?

Tags: python, pandas

pandas.DataFrame.groupby supports grouping by a function(s) of the row or column indexes.  There does not seem to be similar support for pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.

e.g. I can group by col1 being even with...

```
f = lambda r: df.ix[r, 'col1']%2==1
df.groupby(f)
```

but I can't [so far as I can see] sort by say the absolute value of col1 by doing...

```
import numpy as np
f = lambda r: np.abs(df.ix[r, 'col1'])
df.sort_values(by=f)
```

which seems somewhat peculiar.

Comment: `sort_values(by)` doesn't support function. [see here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Comment: If check [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) you need columns for sorting - so need fill helper column, sort by it and then delete it.